# Python, Pyplot: Change appearance of axis without changing axis itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have an array (`grmf`) of 2000 values, corresponding to a measurement scanning 7990 - 8010 MHz. The x values are stored from 0 to 1999.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

xaxis = np.arange(2000)
grmf = 3 * xaxis    #let's just use this as dummy data
plt.plot(xaxis, grmf, label="measurement")
plt.show()
```

I want the x axis to simply display the values 7990 (corresponding to 0) and 8010 (corresponding to 1999) so that it's easier to identify where a peak is roughly located by first glance e.g.

Since there are other functions in the plot and `xaxis` is used in more ways than just this plot I can neither change the axis nor the array `xaxis` but just want to change the graphical appearance. From what I've found it seems like `put.xticks` seems to be the way to go, but it hasn't really worked out yet the way I want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I'm not really sure why xticks isn't working for you. If I understand what you want to do, you just need one more line, so it would look like this:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

xaxis = np.arange(2000)
grmf = 3 * xaxis    #let's just use this as dummy data
plt.plot(xaxis, grmf, label="measurement")
plt.xticks([0, 500, 1000, 1500, 1999], [7990, 7995, 8000, 8005, 8010])
plt.show()
```

I've added a few more values as it's quite simple to figure out which corresponds to which, but you can of course only keep 0 and 1990 if that's what you want. Hopefully this is what you were looking for.